# How to randomize backgroundPosition in JS without using mousemove to animate kaleidoscope

Tags: javascript, css, html

Trying to make an kaleidoscope animation for a web page...but only could find this example but it uses mouse movements. How do I modify so that it randomizes the background instead of mouse movements?

**HTML**

```
<div class="kal_main">
    <div class="kal_cont">
      <div class="ks s1"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s2"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s3"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s4"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s5"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s6"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s7"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s8"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s9"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s10"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s11"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
      <div class="ks s12"><div class="ksc"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".kal_cont").each(function(i){ 
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        $(this).find(".ksc").each(function(i){ 
            $(this).css({backgroundPosition: e.pageX+"px "+e.pageY+"px"});
        });
    });
});
```

});

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.example {
    width: 920px;
    height: 510px;
    border: 0px #000 solid;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

    /* common kaleidoscope styles */
.kal_main {
    background-image: url(../patterns/Animation-Background.png);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 920px;
    height: 510px;
    margin: auto;
}

.kal_cont {
    width: 140%;
    height: 140%;
    left: -20%;
    top: -20%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.kal_cont .ks {
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -o-transform-origin: right top;
    transform-origin: right top;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.kal_cont .ksc {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -o-transform-origin: left top;
    transform-origin: left top;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(../patterns/Brain-no-stem.png);
}
```

Having trouble posting the rest of the CSS code.

Comment: Try illustrating the problem by creating a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to answer without seeing an example, but its likely going to be something like this. When the document is ready, the animateKS function is called. This function loops over each ".ksc" and sets a new background position, then sets a time out to do the same thing 200-500 ms from now (you can tweak this amount of time by playing with the numbers that you pass to getRandom.

**Note:** As it is written, this code won't work. The code that sets the background position is still setting based on e.pageX and e.pageY, which was the position of the mouse in the example you posted. You will need to use different values to change the background position. Depending on what you are trying to do, it may be as easy as passing the result of a call to getRandom passing the appropriate range.

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var bgPos = 0;
function animateKS() {
    $(".ksc").each(function(i){ 
        $(this).css({
            backgroundPosition: bgPos+"px "+bgPos+"px"
        });
    });
    bgPos = bgPos+10;
    setTimeout(animateKS, getRandom(200, 500));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    animateKs();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - sent you a PM.

Comment: @DarrellW that fiddle only includes html. No style or JavaScript, so it's running, but there is nothing for it to render except for a bunch of empty div elements. If you have remaining issues with this response, please be descriptive as to what is still unclear and I'd be happy to help. Also, I'm not sure that SO has PM functionality, so I don't know where to look for that.

Comment: ok, loaded it in JSFIDDLE and is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Dcy/  also check your FB PMs

Comment: ok, can you clarify the code you put above? i cannot get it to work, it just shows the static image instead of animating.

Comment: As I said in the response, it will not work due to the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`. These are values that were based on the pointer's location.  You will need to find suitable alternates to how you want to animate the motion. For starters, try defining a var curPos = 0; outside of the each loop, and replace `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` with curPos++. That should get some motion in the kaleidoscope, but you may need to play with it to make it look better.

Comment: Sorry, define it outside of the animateKS function

Comment: Still does not working doing what you said above. Can you write the complete code of what you are thinking? Thanks